# How to store Id (primary key) of newly inserted row into a variable using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the Id of newly inserted row as below,

```
INSERT dbo.Users(Username)  
OUTPUT inserted.ID  
VALUES('my new name');
```

and when I execute this query in SQL Server 2008, it returns the `id`. My question is how to store this `Id` in a variable in asp.net C# to use this value further.

Note: I am not using parametrized query.

Comment: have your tried `command.excutescalar`

Comment: yes tried now and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the execuate scalar property for your command

```
        int NewNameId = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @inserted TABLE ( id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT dbo.Users(Username)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @inserted 
VALUES('my new name');

SELECT (id)
FROM @inserted
```

not sure. just check

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
            try
            {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlsel, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
              var _id = rdr.GetInt(0);
            }
            conn.Close();

             // do something with _id
```